# Android shared preference, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have the following simple code. It takes the value of a textbox, saves it and retrieve.
The retrieved value is not the same as the saved one.

The printout:
value: qwert
asdf

What the problem could be?

```
val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
sharedPref.edit().putString("Str",binding.text.editText?.text.toString())
print("Value: ")
println(binding.text.editText?.text.toString())
sharedPref.edit().commit()
println(sharedPref.getString("Str","asdf"))
```

Thank you for any hints in advance

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences#edit` hands you an instance of a `SharedPreferences.Editor` class on which you're calling the `putString` method but you're not committing any changes there.

Your second `sharedPref.edit().commit()` just gets a new instance of `SharedPreferences.Editor` without any editions and calls `commit` with no changes.

Try the following

```kotlin
val editor = sharedPrefs.editor()

editor.putString("key", "value")
editor.commit()

return sharedPrefs.getString("key", "defaultValue")
```

A more idiomatic approach would be to use the `apply` function from the kotlin stdlib:

```kotlin
sharedPrefs.edit().apply {
  putString("key", "value")
  commit()
}
```

Comment: Also, since apply() is async, it may not display the saved value instantly. But I doubt it would be an issue on the real app implementation.

Comment: I meant `apply` from the kotlin's stdlib, but you're right. You can persist changes using `SharedPreferences.Editor#apply` (which is **asynchronous**) or `SharedPreferences.Editor#commit` which is **synchronous**. Very good point to bring up

Comment: @MichiBros, apply() is synchronous on the in-memory instance of SharedPreferences so the value is definitely immediately available, but it’s not necessarily written to disk by the time apply() returns.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try like this**

```
//For Add String Value in sharedPreferences
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
    with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
        putString("yourStringKey", "Hello World")
        apply()
    }
    
//Here get enter string value from sharedPreferences other activity 
    val sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("key", MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
    val string = sharedPreferences1.getString("yourStringKey", "hi") //"hi" is default value
    Log.e("sharedPreferences1", "sharedPreferences1 Val is -->> $string")
```

For More Information, you can refer to [official android documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#kotlin)